# Force ClickOnce - application to be started offline?

Tags: .net, deployment, clickonce

I have a click once application here that needs to be started offline exclusively sometimes.

Reason is that it needs to be started VERY early during boot, at a point when there is no network connection yet, also it must not wait for any network connectivity.

I know, this requirement seems strange, but it has legacy reasons.

What do you think?

Comment: Are you asking how to stop the application checking for updates?

Comment: Moreso, I'm asking how to stop the application to contact the Internet at all. What I want is the application to start as if there has never been an Internet at all.

Comment: It should start even though no internet is available -- does it not do that? How are you setting it to start? I have found that putting it in the startup folder doesn't work, at least not consistently, but there is somewhere you can put it in the registry. I can track that information down if you need it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to stop an application deployed via ClickOnce from checking for updates do the following:

In the Solution Explorer right click over the project name and select "Properties".

Then select the "Publish" tab (bottom of the list).

Then select "Updates..." and clear the first option "The application should check for updates".

Save, rebuild and then deploy this version. The old version will check for updates install this and then never check for updates again.